# TypeScript configuration for Rollup

Tags: typescript, rollup, typescript-module-resolution

I'm using Rollup with Typescript with the following configuration:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ESNext"
    }
}
```

This causes problems with importing plugins. For example, when I import the `node-resolve` plugin using:

```
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
```

I am given the error:

> Cannot find module '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'nodenext', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

I then added the following line to my `tsconfig.json` under `compilerOptions`:

```
"moduleResolution": "NodeNext"
```

This allows me to successfully import the plugins, however if I try an use the plugin with `resolve()` I am given the following error (import path trimmed):

> This expression is not callable.
> Type 'typeof import(".../node_modules/@rollup/plugin-node-resolve/types/index")' has no call signatures.

The only way I have found of solving this is by setting `moduleResolution` to `Node`, however this is not recommended. What is causing this problem and what is the best way to solve it without resorting to using `Node` for `moduleResolution`?